# Odoo 8 how to inherit module from another database

Tags: database, odoo

i have two modules M1 and M2 the M1 is installed in database's server and the other is installed in another database'client
it's possible to inherit from another module to access data of other database???

Comment: just use psycopg2 for fill the data in that case  , at a time by default odoo hold only one db cursor .